# Is there any way to create a "Free-write" section for a Chatbot?

Tags: javascript, interface, dialogflow-es, chatbot, rasa

Quite new here and have been using Dialogflow and rasa to try making a chatbot for user reports, Stuck at a certain segment where I want the user to "report" to the bot what it has done for the day, regardless of the content the bot will reply with a "Thanks for your time" response and saves the user's response, I can't seem to figure this out, as the bot will try to analyze the layer of texts the user sends and then goes to default fallback intent....

Comment: hello albert, i find it hard to understand your question... could you please explain a bit more and show some code of what you've tried? also this link gives you good hints how to ask question you might get valuable answers to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh sorry for the hard to understand question, So I wanted to create a segment where My bot will ask the user How is their day going, and after their response (Be it bad or good) I will make the bot prompt the user, Care to explain how so? and then the user will type out what happened during that day and what caused them to feel like that. and afterwards i wanted the bot to reply with a thank you message instead of always going to the fallback intent...

Comment: @Argee I'm also quite new to all this things... Rasa, Dialogflow, React, Javascript and stackoverflow itself, trying to learn and use them...thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

You will need FormAction for free write action (given you don't want any intent for it).

#### In the actions.py, add following code

```
class FormFreeText(FormAction):
    def name(self):
        return "form_free_text"

    @staticmethod
    def required_slots(tracker):
        return ["free_text"]

    def slot_mappings(self):
        return {
            "free_text": self.from_text()
        }

    def submit(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        return []
```

#### In domain.yml, add following lines

```
slots:
  free_text:
    type: unfeaturized

responses:
  utter_ask_free_text:
     - text: "Please enter the text for your report"

actions:
  - form_free_text
```

#### In stories.md, add the following lines where ever you want user input.

```
- form_free_text
- form{'name':'form_free_text'}
- form{'name':null}
```

There are some naming convenstions like using utter_ask to ask any question using FormAction.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In **DialogFlow** your option is to use a fulfilment which allows to drive the conversation logic using events, for example:

- user answers what's wrong or good about the day
- webhook receives the payload with the answer and the associated intent (or better define an action)
- webhook triggers an event (EVENT_DONE)
- the event (EVENT_DONE) belongs to an intent (THANK_YOU) which sends a response to the user

In **Rasa** the options are to either train an intent (inform) with training data (you can still capture/recognise what the user talks about) or use an FormAction where user input is captured in a slot (even if you don't really need to use/store it)

Comment: If I made an intent and then trained it, how would it work? Sorry that I can't wrap my head around it, because the user's reply will be vastly different depending on their days/activities right? a FormAction? Okay Thank you for the response! I will look up on more information regarding the FormAction slot!